# Import error -- No module Named myfile python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror

Ok I am new to doing these imports in python and calling python files to be imported.

My directory structure looks like this.

```
  dir1
  |-__init__.py
  |-file1.py
  |-dir2
  |---|-__init.py__
  |---|-file2.py
  |---|-file3.py
      |---|-dir3
      |-----|-__init.py
      |-----|-file4.py
```

I want to import file 2 from dir3 level

This is what I did

from dir1.dir2.file2 import whatever

I get Import error: No module named dir1.dir2.file2

I tried a lot of options to set my python path, but I am not able to get the import working. It just might be an easy fix but am not able to see it. Your suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load a file from dir3 level (e.g. file4), you could use relative paths:

```
from ..file2 import foo
```

though this is highly discouraged normally.

Comment: Actually tried this out and it threw a value error saying it is not a part of the module

Comment: This should work so there might be else something wrong - maybe with your package setup isn't correct? (dir2/__init.py__ should be dir2/__init__.py and dir3/__init.py should also be dir3/__init__.py)